# Digital Signature Verification for more than 256 length

Tags: java

I am using RSA algorithm for the verification of digital signature in which take a 256 length.
But I have to verify packets which have a variable length of signature like(344,328). If I will use RSA then got error below.

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 328 but was expecting 256..

So which Algo I use which will verify signature of variable length?

Comment: How was the signature created? Don't but the data to be signed in the RSA signature, that is insecure! Only sign the hash (use a common RSA signature standard for that). Note that for an RSA2048 bit key the maximum data size is 256 bytes, this is a mathematical fact and can't be changed by anybody!

Comment: Actually I am Working on Bank Project in which i have no information about how they are created but I got incoming packed(from bank whose lenght is 344,328) which have to verify from my side....Is it possible to verify signature of more than 256 lenght

Comment: Then way don't you use the methods provided by Java for verifying an RSA signature? Anyway you have to know which standard is used for signature generation if you want to verify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Signature length will be fix 256 but In the case of 344 signature length they were encrypted the generated signature using Base64. Firstly I've to decrypt the signature bytes then verify.